# How to set an array with inputbox and then loop an inputbox with numbers for the array vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, inputbox

**Update.**

I fixed up the first input box, to set the array but now when I am trying to use the second inputbox to put the values into the array, I'm not sure how to loop it in so it collects all of those values I'm inputting. Would I have to have a seperate storage for each of the values that are input to collect them or could you just input them and they are looped in? Any examples or information would be muchly appreciated.

A method should accept an array to sort from the user. The size of the array is also to 
be determined by the user. Use Input Box’s for this functionality – one to get the size of 
the array and then one for each string in the array.

```
Dim Numbers() As Integer
Dim value As Integer = InputBox("Enter size of Array", "Array Size", 0)
ReDim Numbers(value - 1) ' You need to minus 1 value as the array starts at 0

txtOutput.Text = "Unsorted array: " & vbCrLf

For Each i As Integer In Numbers
        Numbers(value - 1) = InputBox("Enter numbers in your Array", "Numbers in Array", 0)
        txtOutput.Text &= i + 1 & vbTab ' +1 in there because last value is 1 less than input.
    Next i

    txtOutput.Text &= vbCrLf & "Sorted array: " & vbCrLf

    mergeSort(Numbers, 0, Numbers.Length - 1)

    For Each i As Integer In Numbers
        txtOutput.Text &= i & vbTab
    Next
```

[image: MergeSort System]

Comment: -1 ask a specific question. We shouldn't need to guess what you have an issue with. Also, is this a homework project?

Comment: Okay, I got the input to set the array working now. But my problem is, trying to input values into that array, like how would I loop it to work for each part of the array. When I run it, put in the values. Only the last value is set.

Comment: This really isn't how SO works. But, some advice to your problem would be to follow the answer below. jmcilhinney gives great advice and a spot on answer. Once you have attempted to apply his suggestion,  come back, edit your code to reflect this, and we can try to help you with specific problems. hint:(create a for loop that loops the size of the array (your first input box) and then prompt the user inside the for loop for the value to insert into the array.)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're using `InputBox` isn't really relevant. `InputBox` is just a way to get input. How you use that input is exactly the same regardless of where the input came from.

Once you know the size of the array you need to use a loop. a `For` loop will allow you to get input from the user and set each array element by index.